# REGEXP in MySQL for a $var with or without dot

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking for a `REGEXP` pattern that match. I already looked around any topic but nothing found.

example :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.value REGEXP '5'
```

if table.value contain `'1.4.55.71'` then `5` must be `false`, but `55` must be true

Do you know a regex pattern that can do the job ?

table.value can contain different values, like `'45.55'` or `'32'`. But if more than one value, there is always a dot between.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern seems to work well :

SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.value REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])5([^0-9]|$)'

where '5' is the known value to look for.

Do you agree ?